# $\mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ \emptyset\right\}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Recall. An open set is a set of the form $\bigcup U$ where $U$ is a set of open intervals.

- $\mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ \emptyset\right\}$ is open.

Proof. $\mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ \emptyset\right\}=\left( -\infty ,0\right) \cup\left( 0,\infty \right)
$.

This question is from my lecture notes. I think, there is a typo that this question should be $\mathbb{R} \backslash \left\{ 0\right\}$ is open, right?

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is probably a typo. Indeed, $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\} = (-\infty, 0)\cup(0,\infty)$ which is an open set.

---

However, funnily enough, the set $\mathbb R\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ is **also** an open set.

Depending on your definition of real numbers, $\emptyset$ may actually be a number (usually $0$) which means $\mathbb R\setminus \{\emptyset\} = (-\infty, \emptyset)\cup(\emptyset, \infty)$ which is open, or if $\emptyset\notin \mathbb R$, you have $\mathbb R\setminus\{\emptyset\} = \mathbb R$ which is an open set.

But yeah, probably a typo.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: Well, that depends on how exactly you define the real numbers...

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right. But if you define it through Dedekind cuts, then $\emptyset$ is not a real number. But yeah, I edited my answer. It's all nitpicking, since it's probably a typo anyway.

Comment: Oh, yeah. But you know how mathematicians are... they live for this sort of technical nitpicking. (Which is why I often hate talking to mathematicians, myself included... :P)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know I know. After all, I started it :)

Comment: Well... Technically the OP started it. :P

Comment: Great work guys. Now every undergraduate just learning topology and doesn't have a background in axiomatic set theory just ran away crying...............